# Custom representation of C++ variables in VScode inspector

Tags: c++, variables, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am working on a C++ project for which would be really useful to see the string representation of variables in VScode's variable inspector.

How can I implement a custom representation of variables in the inspector? I have already tried overloading the `<<` operator, but with no success.

```
// in header file
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Tokens::Token const& token);

// in implementation file
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Tokens::Token const& token)
{   
    // write representation to stream
    return stream;
}
```

I know there are no errors in the `operator<<` function because printing to the console via `std::cout << *token << std::endl;` works fine.

This is what I would like to achieve

[image: Expected behaviour]

Thanks in advance